# How to prevent page break in Html print for title of image (is there a <printgroup> tag)

Tags: html, printing

Hi is there a way/tag to group divs `<div class="print always on one page"> <div1> <div2> </div>`. I want to print a image (svg) and the title. Both shall always be printed on the same page.

I invoke the js  code `function printInvoke() { window.print(); }` from my html page. How can I group div-Title and div-Image to be one at print time?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you make it an image caption?

Comment: @mplungian I don't understand how to do this. <img/> has no closing tag. I have a <h4> and a <div> inside  is then my <sgv>

Comment: [FIGCaption](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [figcaption?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption) and page-break

```css
div figure {
  page-break-before: auto;
  page-break-after: auto;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <figure>
    <figcaption>Caption 1</figcaption>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="grid" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="none" stroke="lightblue" />
        </pattern>
      </defs>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)" />
      <rect x="25%" y="25%" width="50%" height="50%" fill="rgba(255,0,0,0.5)"></rect>
      <ellipse cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="25%" ry="25%" fill="rgba(0,255,0,0.5)"></ellipse>
      <polygon points="125,250 250,125 375,250 250,375" fill="rgba(0,0,255,0.5)"></polygon>
      <path d="M 187.5,187.5 h 125 v 125 h -125 z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"></path>
    </svg>
  </figure>
</div>

<div>
  <figure>
    <figcaption>Caption 2</figcaption>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="grid" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="none" stroke="lightblue" />
        </pattern>
      </defs>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)" />
      <rect x="25%" y="25%" width="50%" height="50%" fill="rgba(255,0,0,0.5)"></rect>
      <ellipse cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="25%" ry="25%" fill="rgba(0,255,0,0.5)"></ellipse>
      <polygon points="125,250 250,125 375,250 250,375" fill="rgba(0,0,255,0.5)"></polygon>
      <path d="M 187.5,187.5 h 125 v 125 h -125 z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"></path>
    </svg>
  </figure>
</div>
```